# I am trying to use setContentView to import a .xml files buttons for use in my android app

Tags: java, android, xml, setcontentview

I'm trying to call a .xml file called main.xml in a java class called MainScreenActivity.java.

I can't manage to call main.xml using setContentView, i wondered if i had not got the right syntax but i can seem to solve it, any help would be appreciated.

This is my MainScreenActivity java class:

```
package dbviewer.number1;

import AllProductsActivity.AllProductsActivity;
import NewProductActivity.NewProductActivity;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity{

Button btnViewProducts;
Button btnNewProduct;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Buttons
    btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
    btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);
```

And below is my main.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainScreenActivity" >

<!-- Sample Dashboard screen with Two buttons -->
<!-- Button to view all products screen -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnViewProducts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:text="View Products" />

<!-- Button to create a new product screen -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCreateProduct"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:text="Add New Products" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Divyesh,  the error I am getting is ' R.layout.main cannot be resolved to a type ',  I hope this helps you.

Comment: Raymond,  the question I am asking is what would I have to edit in my java file to be able to reference the main.xml file properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `R.class` import is incorrect.

Replace:

```
import android.R;
```

with

```
import dbviewer.number1.R;
```

or whatever your main package is :-)

There are several `R` classes generated for the project and you need to have the correct one imported to access the resources :-)

Comment: That's doesn't seem to be working for me I'm afraid,  when I replace the import with your suggested import the error  ' The import dbviewer.number1.R cannot be resolved to a type ',  I'm not sure as to what is wrong with the import you have suggested.